# another method can't be called while other ones is calling

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem while executing this code,
I called the void function (insertfaq()) and that function refers another one.
The insertfaq() function is successfully called but neither the other ones (actually there is an error while insertfaq() function but it doesn't matter).

The program should be running well. When insertfaq() function is called, the next pisahkeyword() should be running well and it includes checkkeyword() function too. But the checkkeyword() never ran and there is no error display.

Here the code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 *
 * @author Pcs.Aulia.Ardy
 */
public class userfungsi {

    //getting basic id
    public String idUser;
    String tanggal = "01/01/2014";
    public String judul;
    public String isi;
    private final String status = "1";

    private ResultSet rs_getIdFaq;
    private Statement stmt_get_getIdFaq;
    private String idFaq;

    private Statement stmt_insertFaq;

    public String keyword;
    private String tempKeyword;

    private ResultSet rs_getCheckKeyword;
    private Statement stmt_getCheckKeyword;
    private String CheckKeyword;

    private Statement stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword;

    private ResultSet rs_getId_keywordCount;
    private Statement stmt_getId_keywordCount;
    private String id_keyword_count;

    private Statement stmt_insertNewKeywordCount;

    public userfungsi(String iduser1, String judul1, String isi1, String keyword1) {
        this.idUser = iduser1;
        this.judul = judul1;
        this.isi = isi1;
        this.keyword = keyword1;
    }

    public void mainFunction() {
        get_id();
        getId_keywordCount();
        pisahKeyword();
        insertFaq();
    }

    public void get_id() {
        try {
            koneksi k_getIDfaq = new koneksi(stmt_get_getIdFaq);
            k_getIDfaq.setSt(stmt_get_getIdFaq);
            k_getIDfaq.hubung();
            String sql_get_id = "select nextval('seq_tb_faq')";
            rs_getIdFaq = k_getIDfaq.select(sql_get_id);
            while (rs_getIdFaq.next()) {
                idFaq = rs_getIdFaq.getString("nextval");
            }
            System.out.println("idFaq berhasil didapatkan: " + idFaq);
            k_getIDfaq.putus();

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("idFaq gagal didapatkan");
        }
    }

    public void getId_keywordCount() {
        try {
            koneksi k_getId_keywordCount = new koneksi(stmt_getId_keywordCount);
            k_getId_keywordCount.setSt(stmt_getId_keywordCount);
            k_getId_keywordCount.hubung();
            String sql_getId_keywordCount = "select nextval('seq_tb_keyword_count')";
            rs_getId_keywordCount = k_getId_keywordCount.select(sql_getId_keywordCount);
            while (rs_getId_keywordCount.next()) {
                id_keyword_count = rs_getId_keywordCount.getString(1);
                System.out.println("id keyword count berhasil didapatkan: " + id_keyword_count);
            }
            k_getId_keywordCount.putus();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("id keywordcount gagal didapatkan");
        }

    }

    public void insertFaq() {
        try {

            koneksi k_insertFaq = new koneksi(stmt_insertFaq);
            k_insertFaq.setSt(stmt_insertFaq);
            k_insertFaq.hubung();
            String sql_insertFaq = "INSERT INTO tb_faq(\n"
                    + "            id_faq, id_user, tanggal_input, judul, isi, status)\n"
                    + "    VALUES ('" + idFaq + "', '" + idUser + "', '" + tanggal + "', '" + judul + "', '" + isi + "', true)";
            stmt_insertFaq = k_insertFaq.statement(sql_insertFaq);
            stmt_insertFaq.executeUpdate(sql_insertFaq);
            k_insertFaq.putus();
            System.out.println("insert faq berhasil dilakukan");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("insertFaq gagal dijalankan");
        }
    }

    public void insertNewKeywordCount() {
        try {

            koneksi k_insertNewKeywordCount = new koneksi(stmt_insertNewKeywordCount);
            k_insertNewKeywordCount.setSt(stmt_insertNewKeywordCount);
            k_insertNewKeywordCount.hubung();
            String sql_insertNewKeywordCount = "INSERT INTO tb_keyword_count(\n"
                    + "            id_keyword_count, id_keyword, id_faq, count)\n"
                    + "    VALUES ('" + id_keyword_count + "', '" + tempKeyword + "', '" + idFaq + "', 1);";
            stmt_insertNewKeywordCount = k_insertNewKeywordCount.statement(sql_insertNewKeywordCount);
            stmt_insertNewKeywordCount.executeUpdate(sql_insertNewKeywordCount);
            k_insertNewKeywordCount.putus();
            System.out.println("insert new keyword count berhasil dilakukan");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("insert new keyword gagal dilakukan");
        }
    }

    public void pisahKeyword() {
        try {
            StringTokenizer sktx = new StringTokenizer(keyword, ",");
            while (sktx.hasMoreElements()) {
                tempKeyword = (String) sktx.nextElement();
                System.out.println("daftar keyword: " + tempKeyword);
                System.out.println("pisah keyword berhasil dijalankan");
                checkKeyword();
                System.out.println("method checkKeyword berhasil dipanggil");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("pisah keyword gagal dijalankan");
        }

    }

    public void checkKeyword() {
        try {
            koneksi k_checkKeyword = new koneksi(stmt_getCheckKeyword);
            k_checkKeyword.setSt(stmt_getCheckKeyword);
            k_checkKeyword.hubung();
            String sql_checkKeyword = "select id_keyword from public.tb_keyword where id_keyword = '" + tempKeyword + "'";
            rs_getCheckKeyword = k_checkKeyword.select(sql_checkKeyword);
            while (rs_getCheckKeyword.next()) {
                CheckKeyword = rs_getCheckKeyword.getString("id_keyword");
                updateOrInsertKeyword();
                System.out.println("check keyword berhasil dijalankan");
            }
            k_checkKeyword.putus();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("check keyword gagal dijalankan");

        }
    }

    public void updateOrInsertKeyword() {
        try {
            //check if exist
            if (tempKeyword.equals(CheckKeyword)) {
                koneksi k_updateOrInsertKeyword = new koneksi(stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword);
                k_updateOrInsertKeyword.setSt(stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword);
                k_updateOrInsertKeyword.hubung();
                String sql_updateOrInsertKeyword = "UPDATE tb_keyword_count\n"
                        + "   SET  count=count + 1\n"
                        + "where\n"
                        + "id_keyword = '" + tempKeyword + "'";
                stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword = k_updateOrInsertKeyword.statement(sql_updateOrInsertKeyword);
                stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword.executeUpdate(sql_updateOrInsertKeyword);
                k_updateOrInsertKeyword.putus();
                System.out.println("update keyword berhasil dijalankan");
            } else {
                koneksi k_updateOrInsertKeyword = new koneksi(stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword);
                k_updateOrInsertKeyword.setSt(stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword);
                k_updateOrInsertKeyword.hubung();
                String sql_updateOrInsertKeyword_notExist = "INSERT INTO tb_keyword(\n"
                        + "            id_keyword, \"desc\")\n"
                        + "    VALUES ('" + tempKeyword + "', 'test1');";
                stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword = k_updateOrInsertKeyword.statement(sql_updateOrInsertKeyword_notExist);
                stmt_updateOrInsertKeyword.executeUpdate(sql_updateOrInsertKeyword_notExist);
                k_updateOrInsertKeyword.putus();
                insertNewKeywordCount();
                System.out.println("method insertNewKeywordCount() berhasil dipanggil");
                System.out.println("insert keyword baru berhasil dijalankan");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the error displays:

```
idFaq berhasil didapatkan: 135
id keyword count berhasil didapatkan: 54
daftar keyword: belong1
pisah keyword berhasil dijalankan
method checkKeyword berhasil dipanggil
daftar keyword: belong2
pisah keyword berhasil dijalankan
method checkKeyword berhasil dipanggil
daftar keyword: belong3
pisah keyword berhasil dijalankan
method checkKeyword berhasil dipanggil
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_tb_faq"
  Detail: Key (id_faq)=(135) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2157)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1886)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:555)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:331)
```

thank you for your helping.
cheers :D

Comment: Would be awesome if you could translate your code to english. Otherwise it's difficult to understand quickly.

Comment: Code style is ... not very good, especially underscores in variables names. Anyway, you already have answer in your exception, you are trying to insert value which is already in your database. Debug you code to find this place why you insert it twice.

Answer (score 0):

The same value of `id_Faq`  is inserted two times. In your table attribute id_Faq has unique constraint. So every value of the `id_Faq` should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

> stmt_insertFaq.executeUpdate(sql_insertFaq);

is throwing error ,  after that you are making call to putus() method. If you want to execute 
putus() method call even in case of exception then wrap above call in try catch block and eat the exception. Ideally you should correct the exception then everything fallin place